# How do I find whether $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm d x$ is convergent or not?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm d x$$ How to show that $I$ has a convergent limit?

I wanted to use the fact that $\int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is convergent. My attempts included doing integration of parts but it failed. I don't think the comparision test would work also. Then how do I proceed?

Comment: Cut the integral in two parts. In the parts near $0$, compare to $\ln x$. In the part near $1$ compare to $1/\sqrt{1-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}} \sim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln(x)$$

which is integrable near $0$, and

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}} =0$$

so the function is integrable near $1$.

Comment: I don't think this counts as a hint, but as a solution.

Comment: @Jakobian I agree this is nearly a solution. But I did not justify the equivalent nor the limit, so there is still a little work to have a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm dx$ converges, so does $\int_0^{1/2}\log(x)\,\mathrm dx$, and it follows now from the comparison test that $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$ converges.

On the other hand,$$\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac{\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x}}=\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\sqrt{1-x}.$$Since both limits$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to1^-}\sqrt{1-x}$$exist, then so does $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\sqrt{1-x}$ (actually, it's $0$). Therefore, the integral $\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$ converges too.

Comment: I don't understand how can you use the comparison test since $g(x)=\frac{log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ gives a negative number and $h(x) = log(x)$ is also gives a negative number.Isn't comparision test only for when $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths Apply the comparison test to $\int_0^1\frac{-\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$.